# How to determine whether a web page has RSS or not in C#

Tags: c#, http, rss

I have a task to do.

I need to download a web page and to see if the page contains any RSS feeds.

I know how to download a web page to string using Http APIs in C#, but how can I determine the http page string contains any RSS feeds or not?

Thanks

Jack

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I would like to have something lightweight, so the regular expression sounds good.

Codebrain, could you please give me a regex to find the link? What I really need is just a light level of determination, which means I don't need solid confirmation on whether the rss is valid or not. I just need to know the page has a rss or not.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you would have to load the page into a dom (`XmlDocument`, `XDocument` or `HtmlDocument`) and check for any nodes like:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" ...
```

This should be (in xpath) something like `"/html/head/link[@rel='alternate' and @type='application/atom+xml']"` - then look at `@title` and `@href`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the HTML into an XMLDocument (which may not be possible if it isn't XHTML compliant), try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead. It gives you XMLDocument-like syntax but you can use malformed HTML with it.

but generally, you would look for that link tag in the pages head..

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to check the HTML for the link tag.

An exhaustive approach would be to spider each href link and examine the content-type and presence of rss or atom tags...

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348#1732454

Comment: considering he is searching for a known tag it's not unreasonable to use RegEx in this case IMO